# javascript - stopPropagation issue when trying to detect second click on checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, stoppropagation

I'm trying to get a hamburger menu to open a div when click and also close when clicked a second time when the hamburger is in the (X) state.

I've added in code that allows user to close the hamburger also when they click out side the div that opens. However the `stopPropagation` stops the hamburger being clicked twice and I believe

```
else {
    $(".NavMenu").hide();
 }
```

Isn't being detected.

Is there a simpler way to do this or a solution to get it to work without `stopPropagation`?

```js
$('#burger').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(".NavMenu").show();
  } else {
    $(".NavMenu").hide();
  }
});

$('body').click(function() {
  if ($('#burger').is(':checked')) {
    $(".NavMenu").hide();
    $("#burger").prop("checked", false);
  }
})

$('.NavMenu').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
.mobileMenu {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
}

.NavMenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 70px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-left: -15px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

input+label {
  position: fixed;
  top: 26px;
  left: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 15px;
  z-index: 5;
}

input+label span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #020304;
  transition: .5s;
}

input+label span:first-child {
  top: 3px;
}

input+label span:last-child {
  top: 16px;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked+label span {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
}

input:checked+label span:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

input:checked+label span:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-405deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="burger" type="checkbox" style="display:none;" />

<label for="burger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</label>
<div class="NavMenu">
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Check accessibility</a>
</div>


<div style="margin-top:70px;height: 500px; background-color:#F00;">

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nzrvwfap/

Comment: Do you have to use a checkbox to track the state?

Comment: @brian17han yeah there's a checkbox to track checked `<input id="burger" type="checkbox" style="display:none;"/>`

Comment: @Beth May I know the exact problem with your code.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM when hamburger open the div is shown, I want the div (.NavMenu) to close when clicked outside of the div or when the hamburger (X) is closed.

Comment: @Beth With your code, when I click on the red portion, the NavMenu div is closed. To close "NavMenu" using hamburger (X), need to click twice. So the issue is with closing the "NavMenu" div with single click of hamburger (X) ?

Comment: @PhaniKumarM yes exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check on body click if you click on any span of the hamburger and ignore it.

```js
$('#burger').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(".NavMenu").show();
  } else {
    $(".NavMenu").hide();
  }
});

$('body').click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is($('.hamburger-trigger span'))) {
    return;
  }
  if ($('#burger').is(':checked')) {
    $(".NavMenu").hide();
    $("#burger").prop("checked", false);
  }
})

$('.NavMenu').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
.mobileMenu {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
}

.NavMenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 70px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-left: -15px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

input+label {
  position: fixed;
  top: 26px;
  left: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 15px;
  z-index: 5;
}

input+label span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #020304;
  transition: .5s;
}

input+label span:first-child {
  top: 3px;
}

input+label span:last-child {
  top: 16px;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked+label span {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
}

input:checked+label span:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

input:checked+label span:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-405deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="burger" type="checkbox" style="display:none;" />

<label class="hamburger-trigger" for="burger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</label>
<div class="NavMenu">
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Check accessibility</a>
</div>


<div style="margin-top:70px;height: 500px; background-color:#F00;">

</div>
```

**Important**

But, if you are using with checkbox, I recommend you to try to do this with css only using `~` selector.

```css
.mobileMenu {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
}

.NavMenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 70px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-left: -15px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

/* add this */
#burger:checked ~ .NavMenu {
  display: block;
}

input+label {
  position: fixed;
  top: 26px;
  left: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 15px;
  z-index: 5;
}

input+label span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #020304;
  transition: .5s;
}

input+label span:first-child {
  top: 3px;
}

input+label span:last-child {
  top: 16px;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked+label span {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
}

input:checked+label span:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

input:checked+label span:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-405deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="burger" type="checkbox" style="display:none;" />

<label class="hamburger-trigger" for="burger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</label>
<div class="NavMenu">
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Check accessibility</a>
</div>


<div style="margin-top:70px;height: 500px; background-color:#F00;">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot but for me it doesn't seem to also close when clicked on the red so outside of the div ?

Comment: Sorry I tried the second version, the first version works! but the click only works in certain parts of the X what is the cause of that?

Comment: @Beth I tried to removed `span` from `if ($(e.target).is($('.hamburger-trigger span')))` from the first snippet, and it will allow you to click the entire label to close the dropdown instead of certain part of the "X". The reason was the `span`s are rotated, so they are not easy to click on.

Comment: @Brian17han this is exactly what I needed! great spot is the reason due to the span being smaller than the burger in the css or? anyway thanks alot!!!

Comment: @Beth yeah, the reason was the `span`s are small and rotated.

Comment: @Brian17han there is a slight part I've just found of the hamburger that still doesn't seem to detect which is horizontal line exactly in the middle? do you get this or know what might cause?

Comment: Sure, `if $('.hamburger-trigger, .hamburger-trigger span')`

Comment: @MoshFeu I was using || and it wasn't working but that is it perfect now using the , (im a beginner at javascript) thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Sure! That's why we here :)

Comment: Thanks @brian17han really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To allow it to open again, simply change the line:

```
$('body').click(function() {
```

to

```
$('body').not('#burger').click(function() {
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't work for me however when the menu opens after first click on the hamburger and I click again on the (X) it does nothing?

Comment: Yes, the `X` does nothing, because in your `$('#burger').click(function(event) {` call-out, you refer to `$(this).is(':checked')`, which doesn't work in your original fiddle.  You may want to consider adding and removing a class (upon click) to get this part working.

Comment: thanks Sablefoste, is `$(this).is(':checked')` not working at all in original? How would it be done by adding or remove a class?

Comment: It will not work. `$('body').not('#burger')` is eq to `$('body')`. `not` means that it removes the elements from the collection, but the `$('body')` collection contains only the `body` but not the `#burger`. You can see here:
 http://output.jsbin.com/kedoya and look at the `console`.